# How to select data from 2 tables and convert NULL to 0?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables,  `Table1 (Id, Name, Email)` and `Table2 (Id, ItemName, Price, IsShipping)`. I need to join them on `Id` columns, but `IsShipping` column has `NULL` values, I need to change `NULL` to `0`.

For now I have:

```
SELECT Table1.Id, Table1.Name, Table1.Email, Table2.ItemName, Table2.Price, Table2.IsShipping 
FROM Table1
JOIN Table2
ON Table1.Id = Table2.Id
--here I need to make something like:
WHERE IsShipping IS NULL = 0 -- or etc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ISNULL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) in following:

> ISNULL replaces NULL with the specified replacement value.

```
SELECT t1.Id, t1.Name, t1.Email, 
       t2.ItemName, t2.Price, 
       ISNULL(t2.IsShipping, 0)  -- Here you pass ISNULL
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2
ON t1.Id = t2.Id
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the ANSI standard function `coalesce()`:

```
SELECT t1.Id, t1.Name, t1.Email, t2.ItemName, t2.Price,
       coalesce(t2.IsShipping , 0) as IsShipping
FROM Table1 t1 JOIN
     Table2 t2
     ON t1.Id = t2.Id;
```

I also added table aliases.  They make the query easier to write and to read.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `coalesce()` and Both `ISNULL` and `COALESCE` are ANSI standard

```
SELECT Table1.Id, Table1.Name, Table1.Email, Table2.ItemName, Table2.Price, 
coalesce(Table2.IsShipping,0) as IsShipping
FROM Table1
JOIN Table2
ON Table1.Id = Table2.Id
```